# Не работает свойство fill для спрайта svg

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, svg-спрайт

Код svg:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="26" height="26" viewBox="0 0 26 26">
  <image id="location-pin" width="26" height="26" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,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"/>
</svg>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: От того что вы завернули PNG-картинку в виде base64 в SVG она не стала внезапно векторной

Comment: Все верно. Возможно ли преобразовать png картинку в векторную? (Картинку png я преобразовал в виде base64 через Adobe XD)

Comment: «Обвести» иконку в векторном редакторе. Эту иконку рисовать минут 10

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: Через illustrator можно оттрейсить или перерисовать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В комментариях совершенно справедливо отметили, что растровое изображение с конвертированное в формат Base64 не стилизуется, как вектор. (fill="red")
В этом случае для закраски можно применить CSS или SVG фильтры.
Но можно нарисовать иконку или подобрать готовую.
У меня есть подобная иконка маркера SVG.

Оборачиваем её код в теги  `<symbol>` и присваиваем `id ="marker"`

далее эту иконку можно вызывать по `id` сколько угодно раз в любом месте HTML с помощью `<use class="u1" href="#marker"  />`

При стилизации из внешнего CSS необходимо добавить принудительное наследование, чтобы решить проблему shadow DOM

```
use path{
fill:inherit;
stroke:inherit;
 }
```

*Изменение цвета маркера при наведении:*

```css
 use path{
fill:inherit;
stroke:inherit;
 }
.u1,.u2,.u3 {
fill:#E5C983;
 }
.u1:hover {
fill:red;
 } 
.u2:hover {
fill:dodgerblue;
 } 
 
  .u3:hover {
fill:green;

 }
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="0" height="0" viewBox="0 0 9.8 14.8" >
<symbol id="marker" >
    <path   d="M9.831 4.916c0 2.714-3.538 8.487-4.913 9.867C3.437 13.307 0 7.631 0 4.916S2.201 0 4.916 0s4.915 2.201 4.915 4.916z"/>
    <circle cx="4.912" cy="4.916" r="2.932"  fill="#E7EDEF"/>
</symbol>   
 
</svg> 
<svg width="19.6" height="29.6" viewBox="0 0 9.8 14.8"> 
<use class="u1" href="#marker"  />
</svg>

<svg width="19.6" height="29.6" viewBox="0 0 9.8 14.8"> 
<use class="u2" href="#marker"  />
</svg>  

<svg width="19.6" height="29.6" viewBox="0 0 9.8 14.8"> 
<use class="u3" href="#marker"  />
</svg>
```