# Область видимости переменных (определений, шаблонов) в SVG, включенных в HTML

Tags: html, svg

В одном из ответов на SO заметил, что на страницу `HTML` помещены несколько тегов (файлов?) `SVG`. Определение шаблона пути в `<symbol></symbol>` было задано в первом теге, а считывалось это определение в остальных трех. Кроме того, объявление `xmlns` также присутствует только в первом случае.
Я попробовал заменить `<symbol>` на `<g>` - все работает по-прежнему.

Отсюда вопросы:

**1. Как рассматривать несколько тегов `SVG` в плане области видимости определений шаблонов или групп?** Можно определять шаблоны в любом теге (файле) SVG в пределах документа?

**2. Почему атрибут `xmlns`, который требуется для открытия файла `SVG`, опущен в других тегах и какие существуют на этот счет правила?**

**3. Можно ли подключить файл `SVG` со всеми определениями в `head`, а пользоваться этими определениями в `body` в элементах `SVG`.**

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="0" height="0" viewBox="0 0 9.8 14.8" >
<g id="marker" >
    <path   d="M9.831 4.916c0 2.714-3.538 8.487-4.913 9.867C3.437 13.307 0 7.631 0 4.916S2.201 0 4.916 0s4.915 2.201 4.915 4.916z"/>
    <circle cx="4.912" cy="4.916" r="2.932"  fill="#E7EDEF"/>
</g>
</svg>

<svg width="19.6" height="29.6" viewBox="0 0 9.8 14.8"> 
<use class="u1" href="#marker"  />
</svg>

<svg width="19.6" height="29.6" viewBox="0 0 9.8 14.8"> 
<use class="u2" href="#marker"  />
</svg>  

<svg width="19.6" height="29.6" viewBox="0 0 9.8 14.8"> 
<use class="u3" href="#marker"  />
</svg>
```

Код взят со страницы вопроса: [Не работает свойство fill для спрайта svg](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1296238/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-fill-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0-svg)

Comment: Область видимости — документ. А `xmlns` внутри HTML вообще не нужен (потому что HTML это не XML)

Comment: @AlexeyTen, то есть, как файлы здесь SVG воспринимать не надо? Это простые элементы? Я просто пробовал удалять все ненужные определения и выяснил, что без `xmlns` `svg` браузером не открывается (как отдельный файл). Ругается на отсутствие определения стилей или что-то такое...

Comment: Отдельный SVG-файл должен быть валидным XML и иметь правильный namespace. SVG встроенные в HTML разбираются HTML-парсером и он ничего не знает про namespace-ы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как совершенно верно комментирует: [@Alexey Ten](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1297538/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-svg-%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b2-html/1297640#comment2288313_1297538)

> Отдельный SVG-файл должен быть валидным XML и иметь правильный
> namespace. SVG встроенные в HTML разбираются HTML-парсером и он ничего
> не знает про namespace-ы

Добавлю также, что и ошибки в написании кода SVG, HTML-парсер тоже пропускает.

И это   браузерная ловушка, которая ставит, даже опытных разработчиков в тупик во время поиска причин отказа или неожидаемого результата работы приложения.

**Сообщения об ошибке нет, парсер HTML просто проигнорирует первую ошибку SVG кода, выполнит команду, но не будет дальше обрабатывать другие строки SVG**

А причина может быть тривиальная, - не закрыт тег одной из команд SVG.

- Это показано на примере ниже, не закрыт тег `<rect>`

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" >  

<!-- Не закрыт тег rect, нужно "/>" либо "</rect>" -->
<rect x="50" y="50" width="50%" height="50%" rx="5%" fill="purple" > 
</svg>
```

- Во втором примере к первой ошибочной команде добавлена вторая
  **правильная** команда с закрытием тега.

Должен быть нарисованы два квадрата: пурпурный и желтый, но жёлтый квадрат из-за ошибки в первой строке не будет  отображен:

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" >  

<!-- Не закрыт тег rect, нужно "/>" либо "</rect>" -->
<rect x="50" y="50" width="50%" height="50%" rx="5%" fill="purple" > 
  <!-- Тег закрыт, но из-за ошибки в первой строке, эта не будет показана -->
<rect x="50" y="150" width="50" height="50 rx="5%" fill="gold" /> 
</svg>
```

Теперь сохраним эти файлы в формате SVG и запустим в браузере:

- Парсер Chrome выведет сообщение об ошибке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Парсер FireFox:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Вывод:

Проектируйте приложение SVG в самостоятельном файле SVG и проверять его, на мой взгляд лучше в Firefox. Так как в Chrome внедряют экспериментальные технологии, не дождавшись выхода оф. версии SVG2.

Поэтому, что может работать в Chrome, может не работать в Safari и FF

> **3. Можно ли подключить файл SVG со всеми определениями в head, а пользоваться этими определениями в body в элементах SVG.**

Да, файл svg можно подключать к Html инлайн способом, то есть просто скопировать код SVG, как в топике, который вы указали в вопросе

Можно добавить файл с помощью `<object>` это делается, когда нужно подключить файлы SVG с большим объемом, например спрайты

Как ещё можно подключить SVG к HTML можно посмотреть [здесь](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=1047)

Comment: Так почему все-таки несколько отдельных SVG на одной странице имеют общую "область видимости", поднимаются ли определения, как `function` в `JS`, и зависит ли это от способа подключения (`img` не берем в расчет). Что в итоге они из себя представляют в совокупности и каждый по отдельности?

Comment: @Leonid в примере, который вы использовали в вопросе SVG добавлен инлайн, поэтому парсер HTML уже знает, что ему надо работать с namespace SVG, когда он снова встречает тег SVG. На мой взгляд лучше всегда указывать namespace, так будет надежней, чтобы потом не мучаться, почему SVG не работает в других фреймворках, например react, node.js и т.д

Comment: Спасибо, много нового для себя узнал. Пока не совсем я свыкся с концепцией встроенного в HTML инородного (или нет) объекта. Видимо, со временем...

Comment: @Leonid ну если вам ближе JS, то ведь мы пишем `<script>` в HTML документе и далее код и правила игры JS, точно также мы пишем SVG и далее правила игры SVG

Answer (score 2):

### Javascript + SVG + namespace

Пример, в котором демонстрируется важность значения указания `namespace` в JS при создании SVG объектов.

Кстати, это один из самых часто задаваемых вопросов в сети, почему при указании `setAttribute` атрибуты объектов SVG не изменяются.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="600" height="400">
  <script type="text/ecmascript"><![CDATA[
    var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
    var xlinkNS = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
    function createCircle() {
      var newCircle = document.createElementNS(svgNS,"circle");
      newCircle.setAttribute(null,"cx",Math.random() * 100+250);    
      newCircle.setAttribute(null,"cy",Math.random() * 100+100);        
      newCircle.setAttribute(null,"r",Math.random() * 100);     
      newCircle.setAttribute(null,"stroke",Math.random() * 100);    
      newCircle.setAttribute(null,"fill-opacity",Math.random());        
      var red = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
      var green = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
      var blue = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
      newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","rgb("+ red +","+ green+","+blue+")");
      document.getElementById("firstCircle").appendChild(newCircle);
    }   
     
  ]]></script>
    <g id="firstCircle" onclick="createCircle()"> 
  <rect x="50" y="20" width="150" height="30" rx="10" fill="yellowgreen"  />
    <text x="64" y="40" fill="purple"  font-size="16px">Create a new circle.</text>
     </g>
</svg>
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="600" height="400">
  <script type="text/ecmascript"><![CDATA[
    var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
    var xlinkNS = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
    function createCircle() {
      var newCircle = document.createElementNS(svgNS,"circle");
      newCircle.setAttribute(null,"cx",Math.random() * 100+250);    
      newCircle.setAttribute(null,"cy",Math.random() * 100+100);        
      newCircle.setAttribute(null,"r",Math.random() * 100);     
      newCircle.setAttribute(null,"stroke",Math.random() * 100);    
      newCircle.setAttribute(null,"fill-opacity",Math.random());        
      var red = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
      var green = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
      var blue = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
      newCircle.setAttribute(null,"fill","rgb("+ red +","+ green+","+blue+")");
      document.getElementById("firstCircle").appendChild(newCircle);
    }   
     
  ]]></script>
    <g id="firstCircle" onclick="createCircle()"> 
  <rect x="50" y="20" width="150" height="30" rx="10" fill="yellowgreen"  />
    <text x="64" y="40" fill="purple"  font-size="16px">Create a new circle.</text>
     </g>
</svg>
```

Теперь заменим `setAttribute` на `setAttributeNS`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="600" height="400">
  <script type="text/ecmascript"><![CDATA[
    var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
    var xlinkNS = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
    function createCircle() {
      var newCircle = document.createElementNS(svgNS,"circle");
      newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"cx",Math.random() * 100+250);  
      newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"cy",Math.random() * 100+100);      
      newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"r",Math.random() * 100);       
      newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"stroke",Math.random() * 100);  
      newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"fill-opacity",Math.random());      
      var red = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
      var green = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
      var blue = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
      newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","rgb("+ red +","+ green+","+blue+")");
      document.getElementById("firstCircle").appendChild(newCircle);
    }   
     
  ]]></script>
    <g id="firstCircle" onclick="createCircle()"> 
  <rect x="50" y="20" width="150" height="30" rx="10" fill="yellowgreen"  />
    <text x="64" y="40" fill="purple"  font-size="16px">Create a new circle.</text>
     </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Ничего не понимаю, чем коды отличаются?)))

Comment: @Leonid "Теперь заменим setAttribute на setAttributeNS"